# html can not display fist for-loop result, django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm new in django, I would like to display my view.py to index.html,

the view.py:

```
def index(request):
context_dict = {}

customers = Customer.objects.all()
carts = Cart.objects.select_related('customer')
goods = Good.objects.select_related('cart__customer')

context_dict['Cart']=carts
context_dict['Good']=goods
context_dict['Customer'] = customers

return render(request, 'index.html', context=context_dict)
```

and the index.html for loop is like this:

```
<ul>
            {% for customer in Customer %}
                <li>{{ customer.name }}</li>
                {% for cart in Cart %}
                    {% if customer.id == cart.id %}
                        {% for good in Good %}
                            {% if cart.id == good.id %}
                                {{good.name}}--{{good.count}}--{{good.price}}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
```

but the result displayed like this:

[image: result]

Bob should have water--2--50 under it.
it seems customer.id == cart.id cannot match.
but I don't know how to fix it.
please help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1. `customer.id` should match `card.customer_id` and so on (`cart.good_id == good.id`)
2. if you have a single cart with a single good in it your solution will still return all of the customers, all of the goods to show a single line on the page - this is not really a good solution.

So try using joins and retrieve only needed data, e.g.:

```
actual_carts = Cart.objects.all().select_related('customer', 'good').order_by('customer_id', )
```

This will return only customers and goods mentioned in carts. `select_related` will let you access all the needed info from `customers` as well as from `goods`.